# How to use Dash plotly with Beeware for Android application?

Tags: python, android, plotly-dash, beeware

I want to use [dash plotly](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) interactive graphs in an android application which I am developing on [Beeware](https://pybee.org/). How may I use Dash Plotly in combination with Beeware?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: It is still an open question, I didn't find the solution till now

Comment: it's seems that it's only Embedding Dash Apps in other Web, with Java Script host or React app like in the docs https://dash.plotly.com/integrating-dash, I think they didn't support the mobile version yet

Comment: If you have your dash app running somewhere you can run it inside a webview with beeware. toga has a webview component for example.